# SSH Into mac from parallels Win

Tags: macbook-pro, ssh, sonoma

I recently bought macbook pro with m3 pro. Because some work stuff require windows api I have to use parallels win for arm to do some work, and I need to ssh back to mac.

I have enabled remote login in settings and I am able to log in via ssh password method.

Then I opened /etc/ssh/sshd_config and changed these options:

- PubkeyAuthentication yes
- KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

I went back to windows and ssh-keygen, copy key.pub into mac under user/.shh/authorized_keys.

Back in windows

```
ssh -i "pathtokey" "user"@ip -vvv
```

```
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\danielvazac\\.ssh\\mac RSA SHA256:jktgR8rCcG18R8QuL0VrpCfpMRN5d/nOJu1OTaPoJ7s explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

When I disable password and Kbd it is just `Permission denied (publickey)`.
I also tried ssh ed25519 key but that also doesn't work.

1. Where to find logs? in /var/log/ I unable to find anything helpful.
2. What I am missing?

Thanks!